# Is it possible to use assembly code with gomobile?

Tags: go, gomobile, gomobile-android

I've been experimenting to use assembly code inside the library that I'm going to run on Android platform using gomobile.

```
TEXT gotomobile·sum(SB),4,$0
MOVW    arg1+0(FP), R14
MOVW    arg2+4(FP), R13
ADD     R15, R14, R13
MOVW    R13, ret+8(FP)
RET
```

So far it is successfully compiling and it is even complaining if I make any mistake on assembly code but the function definition I pass won't seem to shown on exported jar,

```
    package gotomobile

import "fmt"

func sum(arg1, arg2 int32) int32

func add() {
    result := sum(3, 4)
    fmt.Println(result)
}

func Test() {
    fmt.Println("Test")
    add() // Tried it like so to try even to suppress function unused warning.
}

func TestWRet() string {
    return "Hello from go"
}
```

and if I call Test(); function on Java I'm getting this error:

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "github.com/user/gomobile/pkg/gotomobile.sum" referenced by "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-tphaYUXt9nWES8ofkOKnCw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libgojni.so"...**

So I've been wondering is it possible to use assembly with gomobile ?